# Eiffel: escaping characters

Tags: database, postgresql, escaping, eiffel

I'm looking for **escaping characters for a DB query**. As it is a complex mechanism (and also could be hacked), it seems obvious I don't want to rewrite it...

I saw that in the JSON_STRING class there is something for escaping STRING_8 (unescape_to_string_8) is there something comparable for DB Strings (need for postgresql)?

Comment: i assume this is the correct framework? https://www.eiffel.org/doc/solutions/EiffelWeb_framework

Comment: @RaymondNijland Don't understand your question

Comment: You tagged the question with eiffel.. So assume you are using that framework?

Comment: @RaymondNijland thx, I'm quite confortable with english even if my native language is french. For your question of course its using the ISE Eiffel Framework and I refer to it

Comment: " I'm quite confortable with english even if my native language is french" Ok then i didn't say annything

Comment: In that case i could not jet find annything which confirms eiffel is using prepared statements to protect against SQL injections

Comment: What about the argument `dynamic` of the feature `DATABASE.parse`? My feeling is that when it is `True`, argument values are taken from a table and SQL statement uses parameters rather than inline values, so that injection is impossible.

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov sorry to contact you throught that I didnt find another way, could you create the `once`, and `EWF` tags editing my last questions I still not read the 2K!?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific class to handle DB encoding for PostgreSQL.
EiffelStore has something similar to prepared statements to bind [query variables](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/solutions/Query_variables).

Check the following article about [EiffelStore and SQLInjection](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/solutions/Defending_against_SQL_injections_with_EiffelStore)

Forgot to mention
Under your EiffleStudio installation, you will find some code with examples of
SQL Injection.

$ISE_EIFFEL/library/store/test/eiffel_store

You can update the examples to test your target database.